# How to get Enum in PostgreSql based on Enum type (using conditional statement)

Tags: sql, postgresql, enums

I am using enum in Postgresql. I have used a enum called city in my database. My requirement is how to get a enum by using conditional statement.
I used the query

```
SELECT 'Bengaluru'::CITY as TEXT
```

it works fine but if the text is not found in enum then it throws a error. How should I make/change the sql query so that it doesn't throw the error.

Comment: enums are a design anti-pattern. Use a proper lookup table instead. Then you can easily run a statement that checks if the value exist that will not result in an error

Comment: what do you mean by lookup table ? how to create it. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: A standard one-to-many relationship: a separate `city` table e.g. `create table city (id integer primary key, name text not null)`. Then use a foreign key referencing the city table instead.

Comment: I previously used the same but we don't want city in separate table. We are planning to use Enum for that. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Are you aware that enums violate normalization? Are you aware about the restrictions imposed by enums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the system tables for that. 
Assuming an enum defined as:

```
create type city as enum ('Munich', 'Berlin');
```

To find out if a specific label was defined for an enum type, you can use the following:

```
select exists (select *
                from pg_enum e
                  join pg_type t on t.oid = e.enumtypid
                  join pg_namespace s on s.oid = t.typnamespace
                where s.nspname = 'public' --<< adjust here for the correct schema
                  and t.typname = 'city'
                  and e.enumlabel = 'Bengaluru');
```

---

The correct solution is to not use enums, but a proper one-to-many relationship instead.

```
create table city
(
  id integer primary key, 
  name varchar(100) not null unique --<< the "unique" mimics the enuma
); 

insert into city (id, name)
values (1, 'Munich'), (2, 'Berlin');
```

To use the "enum", use a foreign key:

```
create table some_table_using_city
(
   ... other columns ...
   city_id integer references city
);
```

To check if a city name exists, simply use:

```
select id
from city
where name = 'Bengaluru';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN 'Bengaluru'::CITY !=NULL THEN 'Bengaluru'::CITY ELSE "Not Found" 
    END as TEXT
```

`CASE` can be used here.

For more details regarding syntax you can find [here.](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-case/)

Comment: How? If value not present then it will return string "Not Found" instead of error. Don't you think same?

Comment: No, the cast `'Bengaluru'::CITY` will result in *"invalid input value for enum city: "Bengaluru"*". Additionally: you can not use `!=` (or `<>`) to compare with null and string constants need to be enclosed in single quotes `"Not Found"` refers to a column.

Comment: It gives error. ERROR:  syntax error at or near "THEN"
LINE 1: SELECT 'Bengaluru'::CITY is not NULL THEN 'Bengaluru'::CITY @iamrajshah

Comment: still got the error please check the query once @a_horse_with_no_name